# Should I depend on HTML5 elements, such as <footer>

Tags: html, vs-web-site-project

I know IE lacks a lot of support for HTML5  element?

Do people really still use IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question about IE8, it appears that about 9% of visits are from IE8, at least in North America: [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-na-monthly-201208-201308). Remember that many corporate environments are slow to push browser upgrades across their large, managed computing base. IE10 is barely hitting 15%.

Here's more info in what HTML5 features IE10 does and does not support: [HTML5Test: IE10](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie10.html). Code accordingly.

As for *depending* on elements like <header> or <footer>, don't. There's technically no need to do so, as you can code it to degrade gracefully by putting <div> tags (which legacy browser recognize) within the header or footer tags, then code your CSS accordingly. Same goes for structural elements like <section>.